Operator's custom `draw()` : align values to the right side of REDO panel
I have a custom operator.
Now I'm adjusting the operator's REDO panel:

Here is the default REDO's look - when draw() function is not manually declared

all values aligned to the right :



But after I declare custom draw() - this happens

values are stretched to the full width :


___
My draw() looks this way:
def draw(self,context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.prop(self, 'size')
    layout.prop(self, 'align')


The Question:
I want to achieve default REDO's look (values alligned to the right) while using custom draw()
How can I do that ?


Use Property Split
def draw(self,context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.use_property_split = True
    layout.prop(self, 'size')
    layout.prop(self, 'align')



It works perfectly. HUGE thanks for the help ❤️
